# error when merging geotiffs

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, merge

I have a problem with a actually simple task: I want to merge 12 Geotiffs in QGIS. With Raster => Miscellaneous => Merge there is always an error saying:

> xyz.tif does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name

All I did before with the Geotiffs was to change their projection with Raster => Projection => Transform

Answer (score 1):

Lets start to check filenames (if is it with only ASCII) and permissions to output folder.
Also check the path to the output folder, if it is only ASCII characters.